# Filtres/Effects in Adobe Premiere

Tags: adobe-premiere

I downloaded some filtres and effects that I wanted to use with my Adobe Premiere but I have no clue where should I paste them. I tried to look for a folder with files of the same format but there wasn't any. What should be the proper format of effect file and where should it be pasted? And maybe someone knows if I can find more filtres and effects for free somewhere in the internet?
Greetongs and thanks for help

Comment: Also, by pasting I mean importing them to use them in the program.

Answer (score 0):

If the effects are with `.aex` extension this should be the path for pasting them `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014\Plug-ins\Common`

Premiere will not always import automatically plugins it depends of the author and process of installation. For some simple paste does the job, and for other you must follow install instructions.